# Open RouterLink on dynamically created divs

Tags: html, angular

On my Angular4 app, I have routerlinks that calls a component which lists all the details, with same generic div. (the div lists all i pass to it)

Each link open on a new window, with that div and all the details listed:

```
<a [routerLink]="['../../'+ property.concept.name.toLowerCase(), item.id]">-->{{property.concept.name}}</a>
```

My objective is open those links always on the page that I am at, creating a "stack" of divs, like a feed with the divs opened..

Modus operandy: I have one div with details and links like I posted before, then I click on a link on that div, and opens another div on top of that first one with the new content, and so on.. if I click on a link in one particular div, it should open the new div on top of the others..

Is this even possible? I've tried to do it with typescript functions, but I loose the functions on previous divs, only got the functions
`<a (click)="showRelatedInstance(..)></a>` working on the first div

Here's some code:

html:

```
    <div id="orange" class="nextContainers" [ngClass]="{'col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12': true }"  *ngIf="showRelatedContent">
    <ng-container *ngFor="let property of relatedInstance.metadata.properties" [ngSwitch]="property.property">

<div class="form-group row">
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12 text-right" *ngIf="property.isAttribute">
    <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-12" *ngIf="property.type" [ngSwitch]="property.type">
```

THIS DOES NOT WORK BECAUSE IT LOOSES THE FUNTION PROPERTY (just work on the last window open)

```
<a (click)="showRelatedInstance({entity:property.concept.name, id:eval('relatedInstance.instance.' + property.key + '.' + property.concept.idKey)})" class="link"  *ngIf="hasValue('relatedInstance.instance.' + property.key)">
 {{eval('relatedInstance.instance.' + property.key + '.' + property.concept.textKey)}} &nbsp;
 <i  class="fa fa-search-plus"><i>{{property.concept.name}}</i></i>
  </a>
```

THE NEW SOLUTIONS ( ? )

```
 <a [routerLink]="['../../'+ property.concept.name.toLowerCase(),eval('relatedInstance.instance.' + property.key + '.' + property.concept.idKey)]">-->{{property.concept.name}}</a>
   </ng-container>

<a [routerLink]="['../../'+ property.concept.name.toLowerCase(), item.id]">-->{{property.concept.name}}</a>

 </div>
 </ng-container>
...
```

Comment: maybe try with a function to wire with routerLink that returns your dynamic link.

Comment: The problem is that when i open a new div, i loose the functions controlls of the last ones.. i mean, the functions only works in the last opened div..